# php banner rotater problem

Tags: php

i want to create dynamic banner rotater wih php ajax i want to pass the mysql_fetch_array() to an array to create a new array() to create xml response..........

here is my code

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads");
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" ?>';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $title = $row['title'];
    $img = $row['file'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $ban = '<b>'.$title.'</b><br><br><img src="ads/'.$img.'"><br><br>'.$body;

    $banners = array(    
            $ban,    
    );    
    $html = $banners[array_rand($banners)];

}

<banner>
    <content><?php echo htmlentities($html); ?></content>
    <reload>3000</reload>    
</banner>
```

but it is return only one ad not return multiple ads how can i fix that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proble is here: `$banners = array($ban);`. What you're trying to do is include all the ads in the `$banners` array as an entry but you are failing to achieve that.

The correct code for including an entry in an array would be `$banner[] = $ban`. That way each ad that comes as a result from your query will be stored as an individual entry.

So the correct code would be:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads");
$banner = array(); //Define the array before trying to add elements.

header('Content-type: text/xml');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $title = $row['title'];
    $img = $row['file'];
    $body = $row['body'];
    $ban = '<b>'.$title.'</b><br><br><img src="ads/'.$img.'"><br><br>'.$body;

    $banner[] = $ban;                //Adding a new entry at the end.
    $html = array_rand($banner);    //Getting a random entry.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in the while loop:

```
$banners[] = $ban
```

Instead of

```
$banners = array(

                $ban,

);
```

and

```
$html = array_rand($banners);
```

instead of

```
$html = $banners[array_rand($banners)];
```

Answer (score 0):

And to what bzabhi said, define your

```
$banners = array();
```

before the while loop, and the randomization part has to go after the loop.